# printing output of ls | wc -l in a txt file with two columns

Tags: bash, ls

I have many directories with different number of CSV files in each of them. I am interested in getting a list of those directories with a their respective number of CSV files. So I have this bash loop.

```
 for i in 21 22 23
 do
   ls my/directory/name$i/*csv | wc -l
 done
```

The question is, how do I get a txt file with an output like this?

```
name21  3
name22  5
name23  2
```

Where the 1st column corresponds to the name of each directory and the second one corresponds to the number of CSV files in each directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can echo the names and results of your command to `output.txt`:

```
for i in 21 22 23
 do
   echo name$i  $(ls my/directory/name$i/*csv | wc -l)
 done > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs explains a number of scenarios where using `ls` and parsing its output will produce wrong or unexpected results. You are much better off e.g. using an array and counting the number of elements in it.

```
for i in 21 22 23; do
   files=( my/directory/name$i/*csv )
   echo "name$i ${#files[@]}"
done >output.txt
```

Perhaps also notice the redirection after `done`, which avoids opening and closing the same file repeatedly inside the loop.

If you want to be portable to POSIX `sh` which doesn't have arrays, try a function.

```
count () {
    echo "$#"
}

for i in 21 22 23; do
    echo "name$i $(count my/directory/name$i/*csv)"
done >output.txt
```

For a robustness test, try creating files with problematic names like

```
touch my/directory/name21/"file name
with newline".csv my/directory/name22/'*'.csv
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)